# How to always get the same results when encrypting a string?

Tags: php, encryption

I have this function to encrypt strings:

```
public function encriptar($string) {
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), 
                            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
    $encrypted = base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                                    hash('sha256', getKey(), true), 
                                                    $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));    
    return $encrypted;
}
```

The problem is that I always return a different value even adding the same string.

**Example:**

**I introduce:** StackOverflow

**Result:** InT3g0AUXXTrmCAxrlht5ZVe8GBmlgGDMotXuVu11hI =

If I rerun the script:

**I introduce:** StackOverflow

**Result:** ImhWn5vPA / A2NY2wpUwg7VLWAiGBls80Z84fGU303Ws =

If I re-run the script:

**I introduce:** StackOverflow

**Result:** FqvxSsblSwz5riaDnnq7h20PzZTPdk / K + dikLHbLHTY =

How can I make it always the same value?

Comment: You are creating a different `$iv` using `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` as the pseudo-random-number-generator, use the same iv, and the result will be the same.

Comment: @joaumg Hi! Thank you it works. You can post an answer to accept as solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a different `$iv` using `MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM` as the pseudo-random-number-generator, use the same `$iv`, and the result will be the same.

You can either store it in you database, in the class instance, or store it as a prefix/suffix of the final hash.

Albeit you shouldn't be reusing the `$iv` for security purposes...

A more insightful topic of the security implications of reusing the key, or even the IV can be found here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10505/reusing-keys-with-aes-cbc

Comment: Reusing an IV can have massive security implications.  Maybe not so much in CBC but what happens if someone comes a long and changes the mode to CTR without looking at the rest?  You should include a bold statement in your answer to state that this is insecure.

Comment: Edited, and added a cross link (;

Answer (score 0):

The result is dependent on the $iv variable which you keep regenerating. You need to generate it only once, save it in the database and then re-use it.

```
function getIv($database) {
    // fictive database abstraction layer
    $iv = $database->fetchIv();
    if (!$iv) {
        $iv = mcrypt_create_iv(
            mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC), 
            MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM
        );
        $database->saveIv($iv);
    }

    return $iv;
}

// in your class

public function encriptar($string) {
    $encrypted = base64_encode($iv . mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
                                                    hash('sha256', getKey(), true), 
                                                    $string, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, getIv()));    
    return $encrypted;
}
```

However, for best practices, this should be kept in a configuration file.